# Including <sstring> header - file not found?

Tags: xcode, stl, header-files

I am using stringstreams in one file of my project, and can't seem to include the header file for them: (`#include <sstream>`). The error message given is:

```
/Users/lee/..../fasta_reader.cpp:13:10: fatal error: 'sstring' file not found [2]
#include <sstring>
         ^
```

Many other SC++L and STL headers are included, and are all found properly from the expected location:`/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`.

Here's what I have verified:

- Include directory configuration: Other standard header files, such as  are being included from the same location.
- Header file permissions: sstring and string have identical permissions, and are in the same location. string is successfully included, but not sstring
- Moving the #include location to before or after all other header files
- Clean build / recompile doesn't help.

What else should I try?

EDIT: Found the solution- I mistyped `#include <sstring>` rather than `#include <sstream>`.

Comment: Make your solution an answer and accept that. Otherwise this question will remain on the “unanswered” list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I mistyped `#include <sstring>` rather than `#include <sstream>`. Wasted a lot of time on a trivial mistake.